# order gridview list decending

Tags: asp.net, select, gridview, objectdatasource, ascx

I currently have a table of data which is ordered in ID order, but i want the list to be ordered in descending order. This i am sure is a simple question but i just can not figure out how to do it.
Here is the ObjectDataSource etc. I am just not sure where to change the code...
Thanks

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource 
        ID="odsTours" 
        runat="server" 
        SelectMethod="GetFiltered" 
        TypeName="blive.Shop.Tour" 
        SortParameterName="sortExpression">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter 
                Name="isActive" 
                ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" 
                DefaultValue="" />
            <asp:Parameter 
                Name="isInThePast" 
                ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" 
                DefaultValue="" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

    <asp:ObjectDataSource 
        ID="odsBookings" 
        runat="server" 
        SelectMethod="GetFiltered" 
        TypeName="blive.Shop.Booking" 
        SortParameterName="sortExpression">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter  
                ControlID="ddlTourFilter" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                Name="tourId" 
                Type="Int32"
                ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
            <asp:Parameter 
                Name="username" 

                ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" 
                DefaultValue="" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be done in the select method of the object data source.
In your case it should be in

```
 GetFiltered method.
```

You can apply the order by in this method.